# Filter SQL with Entity Framework (WHERE)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a database where some employees are stored with their status I want to only display employees whose value is `1`.

Employees

```
id | name | status
---+------+-------
1    james    0
2    anna     1
3    mary     1
4    tom      0
```

Code

```
public ActionResult GetList()
{
    string searchValue = Request["search[value]"];
    List<Employee> empList= new List<Employee>();

    using (DbEntities db = new DbEntities ())
    {
        empList = db.Employees.ToList<Employee>();
        int totalrows = empList.Count;

        // search
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))     // filter
        {
            empList = empList.Where(x => x.name.ToLower().Contains(searchValue.ToLower().ToString())).ToList<Employee>();
        }    //end of if
    }    //end of using
}    //end of function
```

Traditionally I would do something

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employee 
WHERE status = 1;
```

but I am very new to Mysql MVC and the concept of Entity Framework - any help would be appreciated

I have tried doing

```
public ActionResult GetList()
{
    string searchValue = Request["search[value]"];
    List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();

    empList = empList.Where(s => s.status == 1).ToList();

    using (DbEntities db = new DbEntities ())
    {
        empList = db.Employees.ToList<Employee>();
        int totalrows = empList.Count;

        // search
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))    // filter
        {
            empList= empList.Where(x => x.name.ToLower().Contains(searchValue.ToLower().ToString()) && x.status ==1).ToList<Employee>();
        }    //end of if
    }    //end of using
}    //end of function
```

but I still get the full result

Comment: `db.Employees.ToList<Employee>();` - the `.ToList()` part materialises the entire database table into your application's memory. Try inserting a `.Where()` between `db.Employees` and `.ToList<Employee>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fetch all records from db and then filter it. So in case your `searchValue` is empty, it will return all records in db. So comment that line and add one additional condition to check status value.
I assume status is `int`

```
    public ActionResult GetList()
    {
        string searchValue = Request["search[value]"];
        List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();
        using (DbEntities db = new DbEntities())
        {
            // No need of below line, as it will unnecessarily pull all records from db
            //empList = db.Employees.ToList<Employee>();
            //int totalrows = empList.Count;
            //search
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue)) //filter
            {
                empList = db.Employees.Where(x => x.name.ToLower().Contains(searchValue.ToLower()) 
                                                  && x.status == 1 ).ToList<Employee>();
            } //end of if
        } //end of using
    } //end of function
```

Comment: i actually did that but i get the whole result back 
and yes it is a int

Comment: Did you use `&&` condition?

Comment: If your searchValue is blank then it will return all rows, because you already fetch and assign all rows in `empList = db.Employees.ToList<Employee>();` See my answer, I have commented that line.